# How to get detail of instagram post from media id

Tags: php, web-services, api, instagram-api

I have obtained the list of media id. for eg.

> $media_id = 1147661250940270414_242644508

Now, as i have saved the media id already. i now want to fetch other detail information instantly using web services. Below is what i have tried but got no luck.

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$media_id.'?access_token='.$myaccess_token;
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response);
print_r($response);
```

[Reference](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media) from instagram documentation. how could i debug ? 
Note : i have enabled `curl`. The above prints nothing.

Also printing `$url` and browsing prints json data.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is wrong for you? It is working perfectly with my access token and your media_id. The result is:

```
stdClass Object ( [meta] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 200 ) [data] => stdClass Object ( [attribution] => [tags] => Array ( [0] => summer [1] => merrychristmas [2] => love [3] => christmas [4] => family ) [type] => image [location] => [comments] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 0 [data] => Array ( ) ) [filter] => Rise [created_time] => 1451031904 [link] => https://www.instagram.com/p/_tT9PAxndO/ [likes] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 6 [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [username] => nedz3388 [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/t51.2885-19/11296865_494353930737804_199912633_a.jpg [id] => 245135480 [full_name] => Nerida Cole ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [username] => ashleyhughesxixii [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12292658_1933982046828004_675035842_a.jpg [id] => 8121980 [full_name] => AshleyHughes ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [username] => beccao88 [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtp1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11374242_179260799080196_1224064424_a.jpg [id] => 145580378 [full_name] => Rebecca Ormond ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [username] => love_the_shred [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xat1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/10932468_1606801716246599_1519881141_a.jpg [id] => 248027596 [full_name] => Tony Young ) ) ) [images] => stdClass Object ( [low_resolution] => stdClass Object ( [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/12357934_1011207135587426_1185326237_n.jpg [width] => 320 [height] => 320 ) [thumbnail] => stdClass Object ( [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12357934_1011207135587426_1185326237_n.jpg [width] => 150 [height] => 150 ) [standard_resolution] => stdClass Object ( [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12357934_1011207135587426_1185326237_n.jpg [width] => 640 [height] => 640 ) ) [users_in_photo] => Array ( ) [caption] => stdClass Object ( [created_time] => 1451031904 [text] => Merry Christmas to all xx #christmas #merrychristmas #family #love #summer [from] => stdClass Object ( [username] => brooklyne91 [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12276893_1526872547628928_24812970_a.jpg [id] => 242644508 [full_name] => Broooke Ellis ) [id] => 1147661252576048439 ) [user_has_liked] => [id] => 1147661250940270414_242644508 [user] => stdClass Object ( [username] => brooklyne91 [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12276893_1526872547628928_24812970_a.jpg [id] => 242644508 [full_name] => Broooke Ellis ) ) )
```

Then you can split this data individually to how you please.

Comment: yeah, i am also looking for where did i go wrong. Even printing url on browser gives me json data

Comment: That is the result. You want to get JSON data, then you have to split it up using your knowledge in PHP.

Comment: before decoding json step, `$response = file_get_contents($url);` returns me nothing.

Comment: I have a file with your exact code and this line `print_r($response);` prints out the JSON data.

Comment: Ok, not printing here tho, and i am wondering why it's not printing in my case.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct access token! If that's still not working, check either your error log or turn errors on so you can see the underlying issue that's causing this.

Comment: `143658295.1677ed0.2dd45e4540ee4ffcb34b98b9a25da9e8` this is my token access. and there is no console error or any hint of failure. And printing this url on browser is correct as well `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/1147661250940270414_242644508?access_token=143658295.1677ed0.2dd45e4540ee4ffcb34b98b9a25da9e8` (And this is what i obtained by printing `$url`)

Comment: It appears that this access token is invalid as when I open that url it says: "The access_token provided is invalid."

Comment: This is probably a better way to generate an access token: http://bobmckay.com/web/simple-tutorial-for-getting-an-instagram-clientid-and-access-token/

Comment: enabling `openssl` in php.ini solved my issue, thank you.